# dig is not returning all the IP-addresses of a hostname

Tags: dig

I'm trying to get all IP-addresses of a hostname. But dig actually just returns a subset of ips assigned to a host.
For example, this hostname `e.crashlytics.com` is assigned to multiple cnames. Every time I do `dig +short e.crashlytics.com`, I would get only list of IPs associated with a single cname. How could I get all IPs?

Answer (score 1):

It's because the DNS servers of AWS ELB return a differrent CNAME to each query of yours with specific policies of its own.  Ask AWS for possible CNAMEs and As for your domain they will return.

```
# host -t ns crashlytics.com
crashlytics.com name server ns-279.awsdns-34.com.
crashlytics.com name server ns-1609.awsdns-09.co.uk.
crashlytics.com name server ns-1226.awsdns-25.org.
crashlytics.com name server ns-968.awsdns-57.net.

# host -t cname e.crashlytics.com ns-279.awsdns-34.com
Using domain server:
Name: ns-279.awsdns-34.com
Address: 205.251.193.23#53
Aliases: 

e.crashlytics.com is an alias for events-endpoint-b-1623273513.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.

# host -t cname e.crashlytics.com ns-279.awsdns-34.com
Using domain server:
Name: ns-279.awsdns-34.com
Address: 205.251.193.23#53
Aliases: 

e.crashlytics.com is an alias for events-endpoint-455714294.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
```